# Why is the integration not progressing with scipy.integrate.ode?

Tags: python, scipy, complex-numbers, numerical-integration

I am integrating a function func in the complex domain using scipy.integrate.ode. I have assembled the following code structure:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import ode

def func(x, u, k):
    #f, g = u
    dfdx = k*x**2
    dgdx = -x
    
    rhs_FD = [0]*2
    rhs_FD[0] = dfdx
    rhs_FD[1] = dgdx

    return np.array(rhs_FD)

solver = ode(func)
solver.set_integrator('zvode',method='bdf')

k = 1+1j
solver.set_f_params(k)

x0 = 0.0
u0 = [0.0, 1.0]
solver.set_initial_value(u0, x0)

x_values = np.linspace(x0, 1.0, 3)

u_values = []

for x in x_values:
    u = solver.integrate(x)
    u_values.append(u)
```

However, I noticed that the choice of methods, described by solver.set_integrator('zvode', method='bdf'), is not allowing the integration to advance. The output remains the same as the initial condition:

```
[[0.+0.j 1.+0.j]
 [0.+0.j 1.+0.j]
 [0.+0.j 1.+0.j]]
```

I noticed that the code works well by replacing the integrator with solver.set_integrator('dopri5') and considering a real value of k. However, I need to perform this integration in the complex domain. How can I resolve the issue of integration not advancing when considering the complex domain?

Comment: `f` and `g` are unused. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: The line ```f, g = u``` should actually be commented. It was just for me to guide myself on what the system would look like. So, it has no influence. Thank you for pointing that out. I will edit it and add a comment.

Comment: I know you've posted a couple of questions on this topic and I don't feel like reading through the old ones. Is there a reason you're not using `solve_ivp`?

Comment: I am integrating an equation in Python and in Mathematica. The Mathematica value is the correct and more "reliable" one. In Python, I used ```solve_ivp``` and obtained a value where the imaginary part of the root was 0.009 instead of 0.007, causing significant precision issues. So, I thought about using other integrators to check if they work better.

Comment: I have already tried adjusting the ```atol``` and ```rtol``` parameters of ```solve_ivp``` (using the ```RK45``` method) to see if it improves the integration, but the value did not converge to the one found in Mathematica.

Comment: Can you add to your question the Mathematica result for this example? Share it for the same 3 x values you are trying to get from this example.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the results right now as they are on another computer. However, in Mathematica, I was able to solve the equations using the LSODA method, which, strangely, does not work for functions in the complex domain in Python.

Comment: I think that at least fixing the example in the question would give me a clue to know if the issue with my original code is resolved by changing integrators or if it's something more fundamental and complicated with the function resolved in python(which is stiff).

Comment: The BDF solver for `solve_ivp` works for complex variables and can be used on stiff problems, per the documentation.

Comment: Yes, I tried using ```BDF``` with ```solve_ivp```. I tested all possible methods for this library. For this reason, my second option would be to try using another integrator, as I did in the example in the question. I wanted to attempt to solve the problem I encountered using scipy.integrate.ode to see if I can resolve the issue itself.

Comment: My main focus would be to try to fix the problem mentioned in the question because I believe I have tried everything possible with ```solve_ivp``` :(

Comment: Is there a way to solve the problem encountered in the example in the question? Strangely, the integration does not progress for those parameters chosen in ```solver.set_integrator```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you care about is getting this working then the issue is that you already initialized the solver but you are asking it to evaluate it again at `x=0`. To fix this, loop through `x_values[1:]`.

```py
for x in x_values[1:]:
    u = solver.integrate(x)
    u_values.append(u)
    
print(u_values)
```

Output:

```py
[array([0.04166667+0.04166667j, 0.87499999+0.j        ]), array([0.33333333+0.33333333j, 0.5       +0.j        ])]
```

Comment: Thank you, Jared. I will test the functionality. Actually, what concerns me the most is indeed solving the problem itself. However, the code where I solve the differential equations is very extensive, with lots of notebooks imported into other notebooks, and that's why I can't provide a more precise example with all the processes to find the final root. That's why I analyzed the problem as a whole and thought about where I could make changes to test a new solution among the various others that I tried.

Comment: It's not like I don't care about the main problem. I'm just testing various changes because including the entire problem would require too much of your assistance. But I appreciate your help and importance.